# Surveydata Package Question, merge columns

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have survey data that has information in columns like

```
    Q1_1     Q2_2     Q3_3
```

How do I merge their responses to just Q1 using the surveydata or tidy package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `pivot_longer`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # 1.0.0
df1 %>%
     pivot_longer(cols = matches("^Q\\d+_\\d+"), values_to = 'Q1') %>%
     select(-name)
```

Comment: My r cant seem to find the pivot longer function, any ideas?

Comment: @ShehrozMalik  Can you please check the `packageVersion('tidyr')`  I used 1.0.0

Comment: I have 0.8.3 - Should I update packages?

Comment: @ShehrozMalik  Yes, as `pivot_longer/pivot_wider` got introduced in `1.0.0`